# Strange and annoying GLSL error

Tags: opengl, attributes, glsl, variable-assignment, varying

My vertex shader looks as follows:

```
#version 120
uniform float m_thresh;

varying vec2 texCoord;

void main(void)
{   
    gl_Position = ftransform();
    texCoord = gl_TexCoord[0].xy;
}
```

and my fragment shader:

```
#version 120
uniform float m_thresh;
uniform sampler2D grabTexture;

varying vec2 texCoord;

void main(void)
{
    vec4    grab = vec4(texture2D(grabTexture, texCoord.xy));
    vec3    colour = vec3(grab.xyz * m_thresh);
    gl_FragColor = vec4( colour, 0.5 );
}
```

basically i am getting the error message "Error in shader -842150451 - 0<9> : error C7565: assignment to varying 'texCoord'"

But I have another shader which does the exact same thing and I get no error when I compile that and it works!!!

Any ideas what could be happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters, there is no sensible reason to construct a **vec4** from `texture2D (...)`. Texture functions in GLSL *always* return a **vec4**. Likewise, `grab.xyz * m_thresh` is always a **vec3**, because a scalar multiplied by a vector does not change the dimensions of the vector.

Now, here is where things get interesting... the `gl_TexCoord [n]` GLSL built-in you are using is actually a pre-declared *varying*. You should not be reading from this in a vertex shader, because it defines a vertex shader output / fragment shader input.

The appropriate vertex shader built-in variable in GLSL 1.2 for getting the texture coordinates for texture unit N is actually **`gl_MultiTexCoord<N>`**

---

Thus, your vertex and fragment shaders should look like this:

#### Vertex Shader:

```
#version 120

//varying vec2 texCoord; // You actually do not need this

void main(void)
{   
  gl_Position = ftransform();

  //texCoord  = gl_MultiTexCoord0.st; // Same as comment above
  gl_TexCoord [0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;
}
```

#### Fragment Shader:

```
#version 120

uniform float m_thresh;
uniform sampler2D grabTexture;

//varying vec2 texCoord;

void main(void)
{
  //vec4  grab   = texture2D (grabTexture, texCoord.st);

  vec4  grab   = texture2D (grabTexture, gl_TexCoord [0].st);
  vec3  colour = grab.xyz * m_thresh;
  gl_FragColor = vec4( colour, 0.5 );
}
```

Remember how I said `gl_TexCoord [n]` is a built-in varying? You can read/write to this instead of creating your own custom `varying vec2 texCoord;` in GLSL 1.2. I commented out the lines that used a custom varying to show you what I meant.

---

#### [The OpenGL® Shading Language (1.2)](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.Full.1.20.8.pdf) - 7.6 Varying Variables - pp. 53

> The following built-in varying variables are available to ***write to*** in a vertex shader. A particular one should be written to if any functionality in a corresponding fragment shader or fixed pipeline uses it or state derived from it.
>
> [...]
>
> **varying vec4 gl_TexCoord[];** // at most will be gl_MaxTextureCoords

#### [The OpenGL® Shading Language (1.2)](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.Full.1.20.8.pdf) - 7.3 Vertex Shader Built-In Attributes - pp. 49

> The following attribute names are built into the OpenGL vertex language and can be used from within a vertex shader to access the current values of attributes declared by OpenGL.
>
> [...]
>
> **attribute vec4 gl_MultiTexCoord0;**

The bottom line is that `gl_MultiTexCoord<N>` defines vertex attributes (vertex shader input), `gl_TexCoord [n]` defines a varying (vertex shader output, fragment shader input). It is also worth mentioning that these are not available in newer (core) versions of GLSL.

Comment: Hey thank you for the reply and it seems to be a very detailed and helpful description thank you! :) 

But I am still getting the same error for some reason!
I have checked that I am actually saving and loading the correct file so I am at a loss here at what is going on :(  Here is an example of the working one for your information:

    vert shader:
    uniform float Intensity;

    varying vec2  texCoord;

    void main(void)
    { 
     gl_Position  = ftransform();
     texCoord = gl_MultiTexCoord0.xy;
     }

Comment: frag shader:
'code'
uniform float  Intensity;
uniform sampler2D grabTexture;

varying vec2   texCoord;

void main(void)
{

 vec4 grab = vec4(texture2D(grabTexture, texCoord.xy));

 vec3 colour = vec3(grab.xyz * Intensity);


 gl_FragColor = vec4( colour, 0.5 );

}
'code'

Comment: @NickCullen: Are you using `GL_VERTEX_SHADER` and `GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER` appropriately when you call `glCreateShader (...)`? It is invalid to assign something to a varying in a fragment shader, though the behavior tends to differ from implementation to implementation and this cryptic error message might be related.

Comment: I was loading two versions of the .vert shader doh! So sorry! Thanks for the help though very helpful!